# How to log to a memory buffer and flush the buffer to the disk manually?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I use `slf4j` and `logback` in my application and use `org.slf4j.Logger` and `RollingFileAppender` to write the log data to file. I guess it uses some buffered output, which flushes the output when the buffer is full.

Now I would like to control the log flush *manually*. I would like to write log data to a memory buffer and flush it to the disk *explicitly*. For example:

```
logger.trace("trace 1") // write to memory buffer  
logger.trace("trace 2") // write to memory buffer 
logger.trace("trace 3") // write to memory buffer 
logger.flush()          // flush the buffer to the disk
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you only log a little, will the immediate write option be usable?

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I did not get it. What do you mean by the `immediate write option` ?

Comment: Unless you explicitly tell RFA not to, all events are immediately flushed to disk.  Check the section titled "Immediate Flush" in http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you. I should have read it before.